# Access App_Data in WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf

How to access App_Data folder in WCF service?

I have placed a xslt file and I am not able to find the path.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath:

```
string myXsltFilename = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "App_Data", "my.xslt");
```

Comment: You should use the static methods on the Path class when working with paths.

Comment: Possibly, but every MSDN article I've ever seen using this technique always uses a string literal for App_Data.

Comment: HostingEnvironment.MapPath() combines the two. There is no constant for App_Data however so you are stuck with hard coding that. Not that it can change though.

Comment: I think casper was talking about Path.Combine(str1,str2,str3,...)

Comment: Ugh.. I *always* pull people up for not using Path.Combine too .. naughty me :-)

Comment: Thanks for the random, commentless downvote, whoever that was :-)