# Find the App_Data path from a WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I'm trying to write a WCF function that gives me back the URI of an image in the App_Data folder so I can display it in a silverlight application.

How do I get the location of the App_Data folder so that I can search inside it to find the Image I want to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Access App_Data in WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480504/access-appdata-in-wcf-service)

Answer (score 1):

Try:  `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data")`